# how to access the value of javascript variable in a normal class file variable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have to get the value of a java script variable in a normal class variable. I found out one solution of creating a hidden field which can only be created in .aspx page and then java script variable value be assigned to this field in .aspx.cs file only. This value assign should occur on the ajax call on the click of my button of the page.(On click i am calling ajax to do some functioning so my aspx page postback won't occur and i won't be able to assign the java script variable value to the hidden field. I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: 1. Send as part of URL (query string parameter) 2. Add to data you are sending back via AJAX

```
<script>
    var test = "testValue";
    //AJAX Call
    //Option 1
    $.ajax({
        url:'<YOUR URL>'+ '?test=' + test,
        type:'POST',
        ...
    }).success(function(d){ ..})

    //Option 2
    var data = {};
    data.test = test;
    .....//add other stuff

    $.ajax({
        url:'<YOUR URL>',
        type:'POST',
        data:JSON.stringify(data),
        ......
    }).success(function(d){});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go with your question, you need following

> Access JS variable in class file.

1. To do that, you need to have a `HiddenField` and set the JS variable value to hiddenfiled.
2. Make sure you have hidden field in `<form>`.  Say it has name and id = `"hdn"`
3. When postback will happend it will send that data to server. To get that value in class file you need to use `Request.Form["hdn"]`.

Comment: @ arindham - i am not triggering post back on the click of my button. the click of button is calling my ajax function defined in java script. So can't use the hidden field solution. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Ashwhani - You have not mentioned that in Question - whether you need postback! Anyways - you need some trigger to send the value to server.

Comment: Sorry arindham but i did mention it may be not properly. Yeah i need some triggering , but do you have any options other than postback

Comment: The requirement seems odd to me, can you specify what you are trying to achieve? Other way is to have ajax call to set value - but that has to static, not sure all session user may clash with that static value.